# A double integral equality which is unclear

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Can anyone see the equality in the red squere is true?
It is taken from the supplementary material for [this](http://www.nature.com/neuro/journal/v16/n2/full/nn.3309.html) paper.

I am not sure if it is relevant but here, $\phi(x)$ represents the density function (PDF) of [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) and $\Phi(x)$ denotes the cumulative normal distribution function (CDF). i.e. $$\Phi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \phi(t)dt$$

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: It is an integration by parts, of the following type: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x)f(x)\, dx= -\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)f'(x)\, dx +\left [f(x)^2\right]_{x=-\infty}^{x=+\infty}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s integration by  parts:

In $\int_a^b v^{'}udx=[uv]_a^b-\int_a^bvu^{'}dx$ put:

$v^{'}(x)=\phi(x)\Phi(\alpha x)$ and $u(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\phi(y)\Phi(\alpha y)dy$ and $a=-\infty,b=\infty$  and use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Understood Thank you!